# What is the best way to mange Time Zones when Server and Client are in different zones?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC app and a Shared MS SQL DataBase in a physical location at GMT -7.

User for the app are based at GMT +2 and all records should be recorded with time GMT +2.

When in .Net or directly from the DB I use DateTime.Now the DB store information at its Local Time.

I need instead having the DB recording the information at GMT +2.

Keeping in consideration that I cannot change Server Time directly (Hosting is shared), what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Keep all dates and time as UTC and convert to the local time when needed.
If your client uses JS you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to do the conversion with ease.

I am not familiar with MS SQL but I'm sure you have timezone conversion functions there too.

Comment: +1 - this offers the best practice advice regards saving to the server as UTC and neatly points to a client solution if using javascript (which nowadays is almost ubiquitious)